# Prefixes milli- and cent- used for years

Tags: etymology, prefixes

The prefix "milli-" means "thousandth" (e.g. 1000 millimeters in 1 meter) and the prefix "kilo-" means "thousand" (e.g. 1 kilogram is 1000 grams).

Why is the period of 1000 years called a "millennium"? Why don't we use the term "kilennium"? In fact, we already use Y2K as an abbreviation for "Year 2000". Doesn't it make more sense that a "millennium" should be the time period of one-thousandth of a year?

Likewise, instead of "century" or "centennial", of which the prefix "centi-" means "hundredth", shouldn't we use "hectennial" for 100 years?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Latin for *thousand* (not *thousandth*) is *mille,* and this survives in words like *millennium* for a thousand years and *millipede* for an animal with "a thousand feet." Similarly for *cent-* as a prefix in words like *century*; it comes from the Latin for *hundred,* not *hundredth*.

Just as in English, *thousand/thousandth* and *hundred/hundredth* are related, so they are in Latin: *mille/millesima, centum/centesima*. The *-esima* suffix survives in English in *infintesimal*.

In the SI system, Latin prefixes are used for subdivisions of the basic unit, as in *millimetre* and *centigramme*. The SI multiplicative prefixes are based on Greek: *thousand* is from χίλια; *hundred* in Greek is εκατό.

While it's reasonable to **invent a system of measurements** and use prefixes based in this way, **evolved language** doesn't work like that. Because language evolves, we don't generally end up with words where a prefix is Greek and the base word is Latin, like *kilennium*.

We can invent words how we like of course; one example is the SI *millimetre,* where the prefix is Latin and the base word Greek. Another (the other way round) is *television,* of which CP Scott, then Editor of the *Manchester Guardian,* remarked "The word is half Greek and half Latin. No good will come of it."

Comment: Indeed, *kilo-* is an oddity, as elsewhere *χ* is usually transliterated as *ch* (in the very name of the letter: *chi*); we don't have kilennia, but we do have *chiliads* and *chiliasm*.

Answer (score 3):

The prefix **[milli](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/milli--?q=milli-)-** actually is derived from, and often means *thousand* not just *thousandths*.  It is derived from the Latin for 1000. *mille*.

The prefix *milli* and its variants is used to mean both a thousand things, as in *millipede* (a thousand feet; not really, but it looks like that), or millenium (one thousand years) and one thousandth of a thing, as in *millimeter* (one thousandth of a meter).

The prefix **[kilo](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kilo--?q=kilo-)-** also means *thousand*, but is derived form the Greek *khilio*. It is used as a prefix for one thousand, as in *kilometer*.I am not aware of its use to mean a one thousandth portion.

**[Cent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cent?q=cent-)-**, derived ultimately from the Latin *centum*, means *hundred*, and again, is used both for a hundred things, as in *centenary* (a hundred year anniversary) and a one-hundredth portion, as in *cent* (a one-hundredth of a dollar).

**[Hecto](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hecto--?q=hecto-)-** is the prefix derived from the Greek *hekaton* for *hundred*. It is used to refer to thousands of things as in *hectare* (a hundred ares, about 2.5 acres). As with kilo-, I am not aware of its use to mean a one hundredth portion of something.

Comment: A hundred *ares*, just under 2.5 *acres.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's what I get for using an example I have heard of, but did not understand.